# Python table plot (limit length of Datatyp)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am currently working on a university project. I want to use Python to read an excel file and plot it as a table in Python. I've managed that too far. The problem now is to find a limit for each data type, such as string, integer, float so that they fit into the predefined cells. Unfortunately I could not find anything in this regard. I would be happy if you could help me.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide more details? Are you using pandas for reading excel file ?

I dont understand quite what you mean by limit, but one possible solution is following

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data = [['Alex',1200.97],['Bob',987.76],['Clarke',345.34]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Income'],dtype=float)
df

     Name   Income
0    Alex  1200.97
1     Bob   987.76
2  Clarke   345.34
```

Lets say we want to limit number of letters in the name column and round income values

```
Name_litmit=3
Income_round = 0
```

This can be achieved by using apply lambda function:

```
df['Name']=df['Name'].apply(lambda x: x[:Name])
df['Income']=df['Income'].apply(lambda x: np.round(x, Income_round))
```

results

```
df
  Name  Income
0  Ale  1201.0
1  Bob   988.0
2  Cla   345.0
```

Comment: Yes, I use pandas for reading excel file plot it with matplotlib.